# Even function divided by Odd function is an Odd function PROOF?

Tags: calculus

An Even function divided by Odd function is an Odd function,that is a fact. However is there a means to prove this?

Answer (score 7):

Let $h(x)$ be an even function, which means that $h(-x)=h(x)$ and $g(x)$ be an odd function, which means that $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

Let $f(x)=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$.

Then,  $f(-x)=\frac{h(-x)}{g(-x)}=\frac{h(x)}{-g(x)}=-f(x).$$\text{ }$    $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\square$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be an odd function : $ f(-x) = - f(x) $ for all $x$. Let $g$ be an even function: $g(-x) = g(x) $ for all $x$. Now, put $h(x) = \frac{ g(x) }{f(x) } $

$$ h(-x) = \frac{ g(-x) }{f(-x) } = \frac{ g(x) }{ - f(x) } = - \frac{ g(x) }{f(x) }= - h(x) $$

Hence, $h$ is odd.

Comment: I think you need an equals sign in your last step.